# Addon url links to index.php after upgrading expression engine from 2.1 to 2.5

Tags: expressionengine

I newly upgraded a expression engine powered site from 2.1.x to 2.5.x by followed the guide on there site. It went good except for the admin menu items for the addons. For example the site uses Structure module and after the installation it still points to index.php. Every other item in the menu that isn't an add-on points to admin.php. Do any one have a solution for this problem?

Comment: Are you referring to the links in Add-ons -> Modules/Extensions/etc, or links that have been added to the top menu in the CP (like additional buttons after Content/Design/../Admin/Tools?

Comment: It is the links to the modules that the modules adds. Structure have a own menu item to the right of the Add-ons item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have to remove and re-add the quick tabs (the extra buttons in the menu bar). The locations to those include a file name in the database, so they might not have changed from `index.php` to `admin.php`.

Go **Members** → **View All** → ***Username*** → **Main Menu Manager**. For any troublesome buttons, empty out the **Title** field and click **Update**. That'll remove the button.

Then navigate back to the add-on (aay, **Add-ons** → **Modules** → **Structure**) and then click the "**+ Add**" link in the menu bar to add it back with the updated `admin.php` link.

Comment: This works. But it is somewhat tiresome that i have to explain this for every admin on the site. I poked around in the db and found the column quick_tabs in the exp_members table. They have put it in there as a string. It will be possible to make a script to update this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest two things:

1. Make sure you upgrade Structure to the latest version.
2. Make sure the value of `$config['cp_url']` - see **Admin → System Administration → Config File Editor** is correctly pointing to **http://yoururl.com/admin.php**.

Comment: I tried step 2 but with no success. Multi language is the latest version so it can't be updated. And i vill try to update Structure.